# Sinon stub getting "TypeError": Cannot read property 'then' of undefined

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, axios, sinon, stub

I'm trying to stub 2 axios calls with different arguments inside a function where the first works while for second I get error. Can anyone help me understand where I'm going wrong?

index.js

```
function getInfo (endpoint, headers, id){
 return axios
.post(endpoint,id)
.then((response) => {
 const newUrl = response.data.url
return axios
.post(newUrl,id)
.then((result)=>{
if(result.data){
return result.data
}
})
})
}
```

index.test.js

```
const axios = require('axios'). default;

describe ('To test response', function () {
let response:{
data:{
url:'abc'
}
}

test('success', async function (){
let stubPost = sinon.stub(axios,'post')
stubPost.withArgs(endpoint,id).onCall(0).returns(Promise.resolve(response))
stubPost.withArgs('abc',id).onCall(1).returns(Promise.resolve(response.data))

const res = getInfo (endpoint, headers, id);
})
})
```